# Any research on learning Bayesian network structure with a limit on the parent set size?

Tags: references, inference, causality, bayesian-network, structured-prediction

Learning a maximum-scored Bayesian network structure with bounded treewidth is rather popular in recent years, as stated in the paper [A survey on Bayesian network structure learning from data](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13748-019-00194-y) in 2019. However, I failed to find out any recent research on the structural learning of a maximum-scored Bayesian network with bounded number of parents for each variable(node). D.M. Chickering(1996) formalised this problem as $K$-LEARN where $K$ is the upper bounded for number of parents and proved its NP-Completeness in [Learning Bayesian Networks is NP-Complete](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2404-4_12). Since then, to the best of my knowledge, far less attention is paid to $K$-LEARN in the community(in fact, I couldn't find out any related paper), compared with its popular treewidth-bounded version.

So is $K$-LEARN not considered as a good research topic anymore or it has never been the case? Or I just missed the whole line of research for it since 1996? Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Note:** The treewidth of a Bayesian network is defined as the treewidth of its moralised graph, by Elidan and Gould in [Learning Bounded Treewidth Bayesian Networks](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/v9/elidan08a.html)(2008)